# exit() doesn't work anymore (Python 3.10? New Pycharm version? Windows 11?)

Tags: pycharm

I used to close the console automatically when there was an error with:

```
exit()
```

However, I reinstalled everything on my new laptop (worth noting it's windows 11 maybe ?), exit() doesn't work anymore and returns :

```
To exit the PyDev Console, terminate the console within IDE.
```

Is it because I have a newer version of PyCharm (currently using 2021.3.1 community edition on my new laptop), Python 3.10.1 instead of Python 3.9, or Windows 11 instead of Windows 10 ?

I can use:

```
import sys
sys.exit()
```

in the meantime.

But it's longer and makes me import sys when I used to not have to.

Anyone knows what's happening?

Thank you very much!

**EDIT : ON ANOTHER IDE (same laptop) exit() WORKS. I therefore assume it's a PyCharm related problem.**

Comment: I think it is a PyCharm *feature*. As you may notice, recently PyCharm changed the way console works: it runs commands in a queue, and you can remove commands from it. It is a new feature, so I expect in next few release JetBrain will improve things

Comment: It might be it, cos I just noticed my tkinter doesn't work in PyCharm console either. I have to launch it from the terminal or with another IDE to make it work.